# Is it possible to include a library like lxml without installing it?

Tags: python, lxml

I need to perform some xml parsing using a machine that I may not have permission to install libraries in.  So is it possible to include a python library like lxml with my source?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)?  That should let you use lxml without "installing" it.

Comment: Provided he has access to a compiler and all the rest of the necessary build tools and headers.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes yes... you can put some libraries source code folder in  your project and use it as a module, don't know if it works for lxml but for *pure python* libraries it works.

Another option is to install it "locally" using this:

```
python setup.py install --home=<dir>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for lxml. It only works for pure python libraries (some of which are not very simple at all, in fact!).

Comment: for simple I meaned pure python ;-)

Comment: Django's pretty much pure python, and I certainly wouldn't call it simple... ;)

Answer (score 1):

For pure python libraries, you can do that. Unfortunately, lxml depends on a bunch of compiled  c code, so it's not going to be generally portable in the way you want.

Using virtualenv is a good alternative, since it helps isolate a project and the installed files. For lxml to work, you'll need the libraries necessary to compile code, which your system may not contain.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to add the directory that contains the module you want to `sys.path`.

For example:

```
path = r'C:\extra_libraries\lxml'
import sys
sys.path.append(path)
import lxml
sys.path.pop() # If you want to keep the environment clean
```